# How can I get 'seen' status of chat message in microsoft-teams graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am developing a extraction tool to extract microsoft-teams conversation.
It is easy to retrieve Chat Message list and its attributes (e.g. sender, html body and attachments etc) using Graph API as following.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user-id}/chats/{chat-id}/messages?$top=50`

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{user-id}/chats/{chat-id}/messages/{msg-id}`

But I cannot find 'seen' status of the message as its attribute, and/or I cannot find how to retrieve 'seen' status of the message.

For reference, microsoft-teams chat message data is defined as:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta

What I want to retrieve is the 'eye' icon status as attached image.

[image: 'seen'ed chat message in microsoft-teams]

Comment: This is the microsoft's guide for GUI user but not for Graph API: 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-read-receipts-for-messages-in-teams-533f2334-32ef-424b-8d56-ed30e019f856

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Graph currently does not expose or support the "seen/read" property of the [chat message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource.

I see a [feature request for it here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/43303302-gather-status-of-teams-chat-message-sent-and-or-r) that I suggest you upvote so that it may be implemented in future.